# How to add dynamic error for form validation symfony using createnamebuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I create a my own form builder using `createNamebuilder()`. Just like this

```
$builder = $this->formFactory->createNamedBuilder($formName, $phoneNumberType, $data, $formOptions);
```

I have PhoneNumberType. inside of it I add to builder countryNumber and number.

```
$builder->add('countryNumber', CountryCodeType::class);
$builder->add('number', NumberType::class);
```

How to add constraint in number that need to be required? I try to use this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $contactNumber = $builder->getData();
    $countryCode = null;
    if ($contactNumber instanceof ContactNumber) {
        $countryCode = $contactNumber->getCountryNumber();
    }

    $builder->add('countryNumber', CountryCodeType::class, ['data' => $countryCode]);
    $builder->add('number', NumberType::class, [
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => [new NotBlank(['message' => 'Phone number is required.'])]
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ContactNumber::class,
        'error_bubbling' => true
    ]);
}
```

When the time I submit my form. It doesn't show the error message.

Comment: can you add the controller code please , this part seems ok for me

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add form after posting, 
You need to use events
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

or you can add constraints to entity after submitting empty data form will return errors.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ContactNumber
{
    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * ..
    */
    private $number
}
```

and framework.yaml

```
framework:
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```